# Ms-dos 6.22 not letting me save a file via edit program

Tags: virtualbox, ms-dos

I can't seem to save a file from the **edit** command on MS-DOS
I have 3 directories: A B R
I am running MS-DOS from VirtualBox (Could this be affecting it?)

**When I attempt to save the file on the A directory:**
'The drive is write-protected - cannot write to A:\NewFileTxt.txt'
**When I attempt to save the file on the B directory**
'Edit was unable to find the path `B:`'
**When I attempt to save the file on the R directory:**
'Edit was unable to create or access the file `R:\NewFileTxt.txt`'

I was looking for an answer on the internet, but nowadays nobody really uses DOS (I do just for the fun of using older OS). Could it be that my copy of DOS is corrupted? Is it the file extension? Does it have to do with the fact I am running it on VirtualBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you used the drive syntax, `A:`, `B:`, `R:`

The correct way to do this is to save it as: `A\NewFileTxt.txt` `B\NewFileTxt.txt` `R\NewFileTxt.txt`

Comment: So I have to name it with the path?

Comment: @RookieTEC9 you have to omit the colon `:` otherwise MSDOS thinks you are specifying a drive, just like Windows would

Comment: I did omit it, still not working. Now gives me this message:
Edit was unable to create or access the file R:\R\NewFileTxt.txt

Comment: @RookieTEC9 Change back to your original drive first! :-)